# Could this be causing a performance leak or is it something else?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks

I'm making a game which you can test out here: http://jaminweb.com/projs/snakegame.php

Try setting the speed to *Fast* and notice how the snake gets dramatically slower after it hits its food. After hitting its food 10 times, it is suuuuuuper slow. There must be some type of performance leak, which I'm having trouble finding.

The following is the block of code that is executed when the snake hits its food:

```
    if (this.boxCollision(BBhead, BBfood))
    {
         this.moveFood(this.canvHeight, this.canvWidth);
         this.score += 10;
         document.getElementById("snake-score-div").innerHTML = this.score.toString();
         addLink = true;
    }
    if (addLink)
        this.body.push(this.body[this.body.length - 1].clone());
```

where the function `moveFood` is defined by

```
        snakegame.prototype.moveFood = function()
        {   
            var bbf = this.food.getBBox(); // bounding box for food
            do 
            {
                // tx, ty: random translation units 
                tx = randInt(0, this.canvWidth / this.linkSize - 1) * this.linkSize - bbf.x;
                ty = randInt(0, this.canvHeight / this.linkSize - 1) * this.linkSize - bbf.y;
                // translate copy of food
                this.food.translate(tx, ty);
                // update bbf
                bbf = this.food.getBBox(); 
            } while (this.hitSnake(bbf));

        }
```

and the functions `clone` and `translate` come from this library: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Something about that procedure is causing everything to slow down. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not seeing any noticeable drop in performance after scoring 150 on "fast". What OS/browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox you can wrap ceratin operations in console.time to see which one is causing trouble. I would recommend:

```
if (this.boxCollision(BBhead, BBfood))
{
     console.time('Moving food');
     this.moveFood(this.canvHeight, this.canvWidth);
     console.timeEnd('Moving food');

     console.time('Increasing score');
     this.score += 10;
     console.timeEnd('Increasing score');

     console.time('Updating score display');
     document.getElementById("snake-score-div").innerHTML = this.score.toString();
     console.timeEnd('Updating score display');

     addLink = true;
}
if (addLink) {
     console.time('Body clone');
     this.body.push(this.body[this.body.length - 1].clone());
     console.timeEnd('Body clone');
}
```

Then check out your console and watch the numbers.